# Limit payments from only certain types of cards

Tags: commerce

Unfortunately, there was no response to similar question in the Commerce Stripe module's issues queue on https://www.drupal.org/node/2853642, so reposting it here.

For one of the projects I am working on I need to limit to accept only debit cards refusing credit cards. I contacted Stripe and asked if they supported card type limitations and here is what they responded with:

> While there’s no simple setting you can enable or API call that you
>   can make to block certain card types, this can definitely be done with
>   just a bit of programming in your back-end.
>
> Once you’ve created a card token using Stripe.js (or Stripe Checkout),
>   you’ll be able to see the card type by looking at the token object’s
>   `funding` parameter. From here, you could programmatically decide if
>   you want to charge that specific card based on the what that field is
>   populated with. You can read more about token objects at:
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object-card-funding

How do I make it possible to limit payments based on the types of cards used by customers? If there are no ready to use ways, any hints on which exact function to override in a custom module to implement the above suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Stripe suggestion I've made the following changes to commerce_stripe.module file and it works perfectly for us:

```
534,548c534,540
< 
<     // According to https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object-card-funding cards can be of credit, debit, prepaid and unknown types.
<     // For purpose of our project let's decline all card types except debit.
<     if ($card->funding != "debit") {
<       drupal_set_message(t('Only debit cards can be accepted. Please use a debit card.'), 'error');
<       drupal_goto('checkout');
<     } else {
<       // If the card is not declined or otherwise is error-free, we can save it.
<       if ($card && !empty($card->id)) {
<         $stripe_card_id = $card->id;
<         $stripe_customer_id = $card->customer;
<         $c['card'] = $stripe_card_id;
<         $c['customer'] = $stripe_customer_id;
<         $save_card = TRUE;
<       }
---
>     // If the card is not declined or otherwise is error-free, we can save it.
>     if ($card && !empty($card->id)) {
>       $stripe_card_id = $card->id;
>       $stripe_customer_id = $card->customer;
>       $c['card'] = $stripe_card_id;
>       $c['customer'] = $stripe_customer_id;
>       $save_card = TRUE;
```